# How to have a a url be like example.com/projects/projectName?

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to know how I can have a website that has links to deeper pages like so: www.example.com/ then I click on "Projects" (that becomes www.example.com/Projects) and then I click on a project (Which now becomes www.example.com/Projects/projectName/) How would I do that??? Please help, I really need these.

EDIT: Why are people down voting my question?

Comment: We are downvoting because you have shown no effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Do a simple internet search.

Comment: I actually did research it myself. I checked on IRC chats, I checked with friends on Skype. So please before you go and say I didn't do my research or I have no effort, it's not that at all, I came here because I simply couldn't find help else where. And if you have no want or ability to help me, do not comment on my questions. @jsve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done with folders.

When you open www.example.com/Projects you are actually accessing www.example.com/Projects/index.html then let's say you want to access the project the folder Foobar so you type in www.example.com/Projects/Foobar/ and you are served www.example.com/projects/Foobar/index.html

However this can also be done with PHP URL rewriting and the use of a .htaccess fie.

Also when linking make sure that you start with a backslash (Absolute URLs) e.g. 
    href="/projects/test"

If the link was to "projects/test" and you were on that page then if you clicked on that link you would be taken to "projects/test/projects/test"

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually to write a Web page you should learn html and then css. While learning html you will learn how to create a link. 
In html a link is such as

```
<a href="/linkToPage">my link</a>
```

Comment: I know how to create a basic website, with html and css as I already know both, I just dont know how to make it so the url is like so (www.example.com/projects/projectName) I already know how to make it www.example.com/project/

Comment: Simply change your link to the new url you just gave me and it will point to that :) no?

Comment: `<a href="www.example.com/project/">my link</a>` and 
`<a href="www.example.com/projects/ProjectName">my link</a>`